How can i achieve this animation in flutter?
Im trying to implement a carousel animation in Flutter where items smoothly transition from the top left or top right to the center of the screen as the user swipes left or right through the carousel   how can i achieve this in Flutter.
Carousel with animation like this 

Heres the solution.
class AnimatedPages extends StatelessWidget {
final PageController pageController;
final double pageValue;
final ChildBuilder child;
final int pageCount;
final OnPageChangeCallback onPageChangeCallback;

const AnimatedPages({
Key? key,
required this.pageController,
required this.pageValue,
required this.child,
required this.pageCount,
required this.onPageChangeCallback,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return PageView.builder(
  onPageChanged: onPageChangeCallback,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  controller: pageController,
  itemCount: pageCount,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == pageValue.floor() + 1 || index == pageValue.floor() + 2) {
      /// Right
      return Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0.0, -100 * (index - pageValue)),
        child: child(index, context),
      );
    } else if (index == pageValue.floor() ||
        index == pageValue.floor() - 1) {
      /// Left
      return Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0.0, -100 * (pageValue - index)),
        child: child(index, context),
      );
    } else {
      /// Middle
      return child(index, context);
    }
  },
  );
 }
}


Check out https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_carousel it has some nice features to tune your animation. You will basically need to add custom itemBuilder and use AnimatedBuilder inside of it. As animation provide ScrollController you also apply to InfiniteCarousel.builder and play with offset to make the animation you want.
InfiniteCarousel.builder(
   itemCount: WorkoutShareTemplate.values.length,
   itemExtent: maxItemWidth,
   loop: false,
   anchor: 0.5,
   controller: _scrollController,
   itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex, _) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _scrollController,
          builder: (context, child) {
             final currentOffset = maxItemWidth * itemIndex;
             final diff = _scrollController.offset - currentOffset;
             final carouselRatio = maxItemWidth / maxPadding;
             final padding = (diff / carouselRatio).abs().floor();
             // ...
          }
      );
   }


Thanks but i resolved this using pageview builder with animated container
